# Read multi level XML in and write back to single data base table

Tags: asp.net, sql, xml

I'm a nube with asp.net.  This is what I'm trying to achieve.  I want to write the following XML data into a single table in a sql server database.

```
- <RaceDay RaceDayDate="2012-05-16T00:00:00" Year="2012" Month="5" Day="16" DayOfTheWeek="Wednesday" MonthLong="May" IsCurrentDay="1" IsPresaleMeeting="0" ServerTime="2012-05-16T16:47:30.033">
- <Race RaceNo="7" RaceTime="2012-05-16T16:36:00" CloseTime="2012-05-16T16:40:08.107" RaceName="F&M BM 70 HANDICAP" Distance="1200" SubFav="1" RaceDisplayStatus="PAYING" WeatherChanged="N" WeatherCond="1" WeatherDesc="Fine" TrackChanged="N" TrackCond="1" TrackDesc="Good" TrackRating="3" TrackRatingChanged="N">
- <TipsterTip TipsterId="0" Tips="1">
  <Tipster TipsterName="LATE MAIL" /> 
  </TipsterTip>
- <TipsterTip TipsterId="1" Tips="8-5-3-7">
  <Tipster TipsterName="RADIO TAB" /> 
  </TipsterTip>
- <TipsterTip TipsterId="2" Tips="1-10-9-2">
  <Tipster TipsterName="KEVIN CASEY" /> 
  </TipsterTip>
- <Pool PoolType="EX" Available="Y" Abandoned="N" PoolDisplayStatus="PAYING" PoolTotal="3734.00" JPotInGross="0.00" JPotOutGross="0.00" LastCalcTime="2012-05-16T16:36:57" CalcTime="2012-05-16T16:41:31" StatDiv="0">
- <Dividend DivId="62406790" DivAmount="80.8000">
  <DivResult LegNo="1" RunnerNo="7" /> 
  <DivResult LegNo="2" RunnerNo="5" /> 
  </Dividend>
  </Pool>
- <Pool PoolType="F4" Available="Y" Abandoned="N" PoolDisplayStatus="PAYING" PoolTotal="3492.00" JPotInGross="0.00" JPotOutGross="1397.16" LastCalcTime="2012-05-16T16:36:57" CalcTime="2012-05-16T16:41:31" StatDiv="0">
- <Dividend DivId="62406797" DivAmount="10828.0000">
  <DivResult LegNo="1" RunnerNo="7" /> 
  <DivResult LegNo="2" RunnerNo="5" /> 
  <DivResult LegNo="3" RunnerNo="13" /> 
  <DivResult LegNo="4" RunnerNo="1" /> 
  </Dividend>
  </Pool>
- <Pool PoolType="QN" Available="Y" Abandoned="N" PoolDisplayStatus="PAYING" PoolTotal="7029.00" JPotInGross="0.00" JPotOutGross="0.00" LastCalcTime="2012-05-16T16:36:57" CalcTime="2012-05-16T16:41:31" StatDiv="0">
- <Dividend DivId="62406785" DivAmount="68.5000">
  <DivResult LegNo="1" RunnerNo="5" /> 
  <DivResult LegNo="2" RunnerNo="7" /> 
  </Dividend>
  </Pool>
  </Race>
  </Meeting>
  </RaceDay>
```

Can someone please show me how to read in my xml file and flatten out the data and insert it into a suitable table in the sql database.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Search in web, there are lots of article described about your requirement. Try this one:

[Best way to load XML files to SQL Server using C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlxml/thread/1d208559-9190-4ed4-9e9f-2d60afdb896b)

And

[Importing Large Xml Files to SQL Server Using SqlBulkCopy](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/kim/archive/2009/06/15/importing-large-xml-files-to-sql-server-using-sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to parse the XML and store that into custom C# object or you can directly pass the XML to your stored procedure and do the codding there for saving it into DB.

Passing the xml to stored procedure and manipulating it there is bit difficult so what I suggest is to parse it in C# and then get a custom object. Once you get it you can do whatever you want to.

Here is my article that explains exactly what you need.
[Read XML file in ASP.NET(C#)](http://www.icodefor.net/2017/07/read-xml-file-in-asp.net.html)

Below is the sample code that parse a XML file and generate a custom C# object from it.

```
public CatSubCatList GenerateCategoryListFromProductFeedXML()
{
    string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(_xmlFilePath);

    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

    XElement xElement = XElement.Parse(xDoc.ToString());


    List<Category> lstCategory = xElement.Elements("Product").Select(d => new Category
    {
        Code = Convert.ToString(d.Element("CategoryCode").Value),
        CategoryPath = d.Element("CategoryPath").Value,
        Name = GetCateOrSubCategory(d.Element("CategoryPath").Value, 0), // Category
        SubCategoryName = GetCateOrSubCategory(d.Element("CategoryPath").Value, 1) // Sub Category
    }).GroupBy(x => new { x.Code, x.SubCategoryName }).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

    CatSubCatList catSubCatList = GetFinalCategoryListFromXML(lstCategory);

    return catSubCatList;
}
```